# Why does the CLAWS5 tagset separate "of" from all other prepositions?

Tags: computational-linguistics, pos-tagging

The well-known CLAWS5 tagset, for tagging English language lexemes etc, has one tag `PRF`, specifically for tagging the preposition "of", while other prepositions get the tag `PRP`, which is for all prepositions except "of".

Apparently, this kind of thing has some use, since two revisions later, CLAWS7 has separate tags also for "with/without" and "for".

What is the motivation behind these distinctions?

Comment: Might be related: [Case assignment: 'of' vs all other prepositions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function word "of" is sometimes difficult to classify, think of cases like
*to be aware of something*, *to be fond of something/someone*, or *because of*. Putting it in a category of its own reduces the errors of misclassification.